# Typescript Error with intellj Editor

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

I am working on project with `Angular 1.6` and `Typescript`. In fact I hadn't got any compilation error. But now I am having strange errors. I didn't change code and even the app is running correctly. But editor is marking these instructions as incorrect.

```
import {auto} from 'angular';
method().then((data) => {})
```

Comment: replace `angular` tag with `angularjs`

Comment: Do you have the type definitions for Angular?

Comment: it was problem of memory errors disappear when i open typing directory

Answer (score 0):

I think your IDE can't find the TypeScript Definitions.

To tell the IDE about the Typescript corresponding structure of packages like angular, you need to install some kind of TypeScript Definitions.

There are different sources offering TypeScript definitions:

https://github.com/jedmao/dt-angular

https://github.com/typings/typings

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/angular

https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped

Comment: the problem is that all the code was compiling well i hadn't these errors.I don't know what did happen to intellj!! The app is working well.